# sqlmap automatically trims response

Tags: sqlmap

When i try to dump a database with `--dump-all` I first get

> [WARNING] large response detected. This could take a while

then

> [WARNING] too large response detected. Automatically trimming it

How can I make sqlmap dump the entire table without trimming the response?

Comment: what is the command you are using?

Comment: sqlmap --url=site --data="post-data" --random-agent --dump-all --exclude-sysdbs